# Transforming a curl request (POST) with multipart/form-data into scala code

Tags: scala, curl, post, xmlhttprequest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have the following curl request that I am trying to implement in scala.

curl -u "username" -X POST "https://post_url.com"  -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "xmlRequest=@/home/@file.xml;type=text/xml"

I have tried the following but I get a bad request.

```
val client = new DefaultHttpClient()
val requestEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addBinaryBody("xmlRequest",
  new File("/home/@file.xml")).build()
val post = new HttpPost("https://post_url.com")
post.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new
      UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password), "UTF-8", false))
post.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
post.setEntity(requestEntity)
val response = client.execute(post)
println(response.getStatusLine)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve my problem by just using another addBinaryBody function.

```
  val client = new DefaultHttpClient()
  val requestEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addBinaryBody("xmlRequest",
  new File("/home/@file.xml"), ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "").build()
  val post = new HttpPost("https://post_url.com")
  post.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new
  UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password), "UTF-8", false))
  post.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
  post.setEntity(requestEntity)
  val response = client.execute(post)
  println(response.getStatusLine)
```